# Curses - Replace getstr input to * (Asterisks)

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I want **getstr** to display * (Asterisk) when a key is pressed, basically its like a password login form.
Any clues on how to do that ? (Samiliar to **getpass**)

So if i inputed **abcd** it would return **** (abcd)

I don't know if this question already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input from the user as series of characters via getch()

then print * instead after each input

[EDIT]:

Forgot to handle the backspace key: -

Please refer to the below more robust code:

```
import sys
import msvcrt

def encriptAndsavePassword():
    password = ''
    while True:
        x = ord(msvcrt.getch())
        if x == 13:
            # When system receives a carriage return character
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
            return password
        elif x == 8:
            if len(password) > 0:
                # Deletes previous character.
                sys.stdout.write('\b' + ' ' + '\b')                
                sys.stdout.flush()
                password = password[:-1] 
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('*')
            password +=x
```

you can read about `getch()` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch)

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`
and i think it wouldn't work because im using curses and not console

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: it works, but i dont use console for input, i use [curses](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/)

Comment: `Which operating system are you using?` WIndows

Comment: The one I wrote in answer should work, as any input is taken from a console only. curses is a terminal control library only used to map the screen with the user input.

Comment: yea, it works, but it prints when the program exits, but im using curses just for the arrow up and down control

Comment: well. this is not a issue, this is a question on how to do it, your code did what i asked, but it didnt work with curses

Comment: The docs say: *The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module.* So you are using ... what?. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: @BoarGules im using windows-curses on pypi